# Is it possible to enable bash-completion inside midnight commander?

Tags: midnight-commander

I would like to enable prompt to act like the bash one, and have tab-completion.

I know that tab is used to switch between windows, but I would prefer to do completion if the command line is not empty.

Comment: They seem to have added it: https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3672

Answer (score 6):

You get bash-completion after toggling the panes off by pressing `Ctrl-o`. Otherwise, in the prompt you can use `Esc-Tab`.

Comment: Obvious, but is any way to use normal Tab for completion?

Comment: `Esc-Tab` is a very smart shortcut. I always can't remember it.